# display nodes of response xml string in php

Tags: php, xml

i have received a response from remote webservice as xml string and the string look like in browser as below with var_dump($parser).

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public 'City' => 
    array (size=374)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
          public 'CityID' => string '421' (length=3)
          public 'Name' => string 'Abbadia San Salvatore' (length=21)
          public 'Currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
          public 'AreaUnit' => string 'SquareMeter' (length=11)
          public 'CountryID' => string '93' (length=2)
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
          public 'CityID' => string '423' (length=3)
          public 'Name' => string 'Aberdeen' (length=8)
          public 'Currency' => string 'GBP' (length=3)
          public 'AreaUnit' => string 'SquareMeter' (length=11)
          public 'CountryID' => string '216' (length=3)
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
          public 'CityID' => string '9360' (length=4)
          public 'Name' => string 'Aeolian Islands' (length=15)
          public 'Currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
          public 'AreaUnit' => string 'SquareMeter' (length=11)
          public 'CountryID' => string '93' (length=2)
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
          public 'CityID' => string '480' (length=3)
          public 'Name' => string 'Agia Napa' (length=9)
          public 'Currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
          public 'AreaUnit' => string 'SquareMeter' (length=11)
          public 'CountryID' => string '48' (length=2)
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
          public 'CityID' => string '151' (length=3)
          public 'Name' => string 'Agrigento' (length=9)
          public 'Currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
          public 'AreaUnit' => string 'SquareMeter' (length=11)
          public 'CountryID' => string '93' (length=2)
```

and so on it contains total 374 entries. My question is how to display only the particular node (for example consider only Name of the city) in php. Any advice or example much appreciated.

the php code to get this response as follows:

```
<?php

$User = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
$Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    'http://www.mywebservices.com/webservice/clientservice/Version2/Service_partner.asmx/GetCities?Partner='.$User.'&Password='.$Password.''
);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$parser = simplexml_load_string($content);
var_dump($parser);

?>
```

@michi as per your advice i have done - echo htmlentities($parser->asXML()); instead of var_dump(). and the result is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ArrayOfCity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.mywebservice.com/otadbnet/service/"> <City> <CityID>421</CityID> <Name>Abbadia San Salvatore</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>93</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>423</CityID> <Name>Aberdeen</Name> <Currency>GBP</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>216</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>9360</CityID> <Name>Aeolian Islands</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>93</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>480</CityID> <Name>Agia Napa</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>48</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>151</CityID> <Name>Agrigento</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>93</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>499</CityID> <Name>Aguilas</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>178</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>517</CityID> <Name>Aix-en-Provence</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>66</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>540</CityID> <Name>Alanya</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>209</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>561</CityID> <Name>Albufeira</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>155</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>577</CityID> <Name>Alcossebre</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>178</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>192</CityID> <Name>Algarve</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>155</CountryID> </City> <City> <CityID>606</CityID> <Name>Alicante</Name> <Currency>EUR</Currency> <AreaUnit>SquareMeter</AreaUnit> <CountryID>178</CountryID> </City> ..... and so on.
```

Please advise further how to display only the particular node (for example consider only Name of the city) in php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the full code (PHP).

Comment: php code??? or returned string ?

Comment: use the `foreach` loop.

Comment: tried -- foreach( $parser->City->Name as $n){
    echo $n;
} but its showing only the first city name thats it.

Comment: do `echo htmlentities($parser-<asXML());` instead of `var_dump()` and edit your question with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following code to loop through the City nodes:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/city.xml');

$parser = simplexml_load_string($content);

foreach ($parser->City as $subnode) {
    echo $subnode->Name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

supposed the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<City>
    <CityId>1</CityId>
    <Name>South Park</Name>
    <Currency>Dollar</Currency>
</City>
<City>
    <CityId>1</CityId>
    <Name>South Park</Name>
    <Currency>Dollar</Currency>
</City>
<City>
    <CityId>1</CityId>
    <Name>South Park</Name>
    <Currency>Dollar</Currency>
</City>
</test>
```

But I suggest using XMLReader for traversing through an xml since SimpleXml is compared pretty bad at errors and XMLReader is in my opinion much faster on big files.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. but i did not understand why PHP_EOL in the loop..? it works without PHP_EOL also.

Comment: PHP_EOL is just a constant for a new line. In html you can use a br-tag.